# How can I display a .mov file in my react native app and make it look like a gif?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, npm

I was tasked to try using a `.mov` format file in my react native app and make it display like a `.gif` would for an animation. The reason for this is because the animation in `.mov` is sharper than the `.gif`. How can I do this? I'm a noob, any help would appreciated.

Thank you!